# How to concat/combine two matrices of the same length to "fill in the blanks" of one of the matrices? R Question

Tags: r, matrix, binary, integer, concatenation

I'm working on a binary integer programming assignment and I was hoping there would be a short cut to typing in all the ones and zeros for the constraints. I created two matrices. The first contains all zeros and the second contains all ones.

I have 34 variables and created two matrices like this (though I may not have needed to created these):

```
zero_constraints = matrix(data = 0, nrow = 1, ncol = 34)
one_constraints = matrix(data = 1, nrow = 1, ncol = 34)
```

Here's an example of the constraints:

```
# He therefore decides to include only one collage.
filter(data_raw, data_raw$Medium.Style == "Collage")$ID
```

output:

```
[1]  9 16 29 30
```

I gave each variable a number so these numbers would mean I needed variables 9, 16, 29, and 30 to be 1 and the rest of my variables to be 0.

This where I get lost:

```
one_constraints[, c(filter(data_raw, data_raw$Medium.Style == "Collage")$ID)]
```

I know the line above gets me the "ones" I need from my matrix of 34 ones so then I tried to concatenate my two matrices of ones and zeroes:

```
cat(
    one_constraints[, c(filter(data_raw, data_raw$Medium.Style == "Collage")$ID)],
    zero_constraints[, -c(filter(data_raw, data_raw$Medium.Style == "Collage")$ID)]
)
```

output:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

but this is not the desired output. The ones should not be in a row at the beginning. It should look something like this:

```
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0   0     0    0     0     0    0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
```

If this is too complicated, I can just go with my initial plan to cbind matrices, which is how I created the above.

If you want that code:

```
cbind(
  matrix(data = 0, nrow = 1, ncol = 8),     # 1-8
  1,                                        # 9
  matrix(data = 0, nrow = 1, ncol = 6),     # 10-15
  1,                                        # 16
  matrix(data = 0, nrow = 1, ncol = 12),    # 17
  1, 1,                                     # 29, 30
  matrix(data = 0, nrow = 1, ncol = 4)      # 31-34
)
```

**Edit**
I tried this answer:

```
inds <- c(9, 16, 29, 30)
mat <- matrix(0, ncol = 34)
mat[, inds] <- 1
```

by doing this:

```
twnety_one_con <- filter(data_raw, data_raw$Medium.Style == "Collage")$ID
twnety_one_mat <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = 1, ncol =34)
mat <- (twnety_one_mat[, twnety_one_mat] <- 1)
```

I may be doing it wrong but it doesn't work. It returns a vector of 1 and when I put it my add.constraint bit of code it confirms that it doesn't match vector length

Comment: You need to assign to 1 `<- 1`

Comment: Can you also show the output of `twnety_one_con`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OP's function, the index from `filter` step returns the 'ID's which represents the column index.  We only need to assign (`<-`) the values to 1

```
inds <- c(9, 16, 29, 30)
mat <- matrix(0, ncol = 34)
mat[, inds] <- 1


mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] #[,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     0     0     0     #1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#     [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32] [,33] [,34]
#[1,]     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: hi--sorry but this doesn't seem to work. It returns a vector of 1

Comment: @EX_Tenn  I updated with the solution I am getting.  It is only returning 1s based on the index

Comment: @EX_Tenn Please check your `twnety_one_con <- filter(filter(data_raw, data_raw$Medium.Style == "Collage")$ID)`, it seems incorrect to me, because the outer `filter` doesn't have any logical expression, it is simply wrapping around the 'ID'

Comment: @Ex_Tenn I think you need just `data_raw$ID[data_raw$Medium.Style == "Collage"]`

Comment: sorry @akrun that was a typo
only one filter is in there--editing it

Comment: @EX_Tenn can you show the output or `str(twnety_one_con)`

Comment: `str(twnety_one_con)` outputs  int [1:4] 9 16 29 30
`twnety_one_mat` outputs  num [1, 1:34] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
`mat` outputs [1] 1
@akrun

Comment: What is the output of `twnety_one_mat[, twnety_one_mat] <- 1; twnety_one_mat`  Here, the `mat` is `twnety_one_mat`

Comment: `str(twnety_one_mat[, twnety_one_mat] <- 1)` output is `num 1`

Comment: @EX_Tenn Don't wrap the `str` around that.  after you do the assignment, check `str(twnety_one_mat)`

Comment: @EX_Tenn  I think you are mixing the assignment here.  When you do the `str(` on the whole expression with assignment, there is only a single value .e. the assignment value 1.  Instead you need to check the object after the assignment.

Comment: I see--that worked perfectly
thank you for the extra help
much appreciated 
@akrun

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
inds <- c(9, 16, 29, 30)
mat <- matrix(0, ncol = 34)
mat[, inds] <- 1
```

Comment: hi--sorry but this doesn't seem to work. It returns a vector of 1

Comment: @EX_Tenn You should use `twnety_one_mat[, twnety_one_con] <- 1`

Comment: that worked--thank you for the extra help
much appreciated @Ronak Shah